# Reproduce RAW Image - C

Tags: c, image-processing

I'm trying to reproduce a `.raw` image file using a small program I've written in C, but every time I run the program my output file becomes unreadable.

All my program does is take every pixel and write it to a corresponding output file.

Also note, this program is written to support only grayscale images.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    char path_in[64], path_out[64], *rev, px;
    int width, height, read, row, i;

    printf("Input file name: ");
    scanf("%s", path_in);
    printf("Output file name: ");
    scanf("%s", path_out);

    printf("Width of image (in pixels): ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("Height of image (in pixels): ");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    fin = fopen(path_in, "r");
    fout = fopen(path_out, "w");

    row = 0;
    rev = (char *)malloc(width * sizeof(char));
    while(row < height)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            read = fread(&px, sizeof(char), 1, fin);
            rev[i] = (unsigned int)px;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
            if(i < width && row < height)
                fwrite(&rev[i], sizeof(char), 1, fout);

        row++;
    }

    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `rev[i] = (unsigned int)px;` — why are you casting a char variable to an `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some other problems with it, but you've told `fopen` to open the files in text mode:

```
fin = fopen(path_in, "r");
fout = fopen(path_out, "w");
```

instead of binary mode:

```
fin = fopen(path_in, "rb");
fout = fopen(path_out, "wb");
```

which is what's appropriate for image data.

You're also doing odd casting that might be munging your data:

```
char ..., *rev, px;
...
rev = (char *)malloc(width * sizeof(char));
...
rev[i] = (unsigned int)px;
```

The `(unsigned int)` cast is unnecessary at best.

Comment: `rev = (char *)malloc(width * sizeof(char));` is used to make the array the length of whatever the image's width is.

Comment: I understand the `malloc`. That was included to give further context to the claim that the final cast was odd.

Comment: Yeah, that cast was odd now that I think of it. Removing it fixed my issue, though :)